# SingalR didn't invoke server side method and broadcast data back to client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, owin

I have a regular running job which is registered into an OWIN host app. I took the project of [stock ticker broadcasting app](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr) as a reference, and I want to make that job like the stock ticker class which is being able to broadcast data to a JavaScript client.

However, after I followed the example, and set everything right, some weird problem happened and I couldn't figure out why.

1. The traffic will automatically downgrade to long polling, instead of using server send event like the stock ticker did.
2. I have called a dynamic method at server side, and defined that method at client side, but it never got called.

This is my server side hub definition:

```
[HubName("healthCheckHub")]

public class HealthCheckHub : Hub
{
    
   private readonly PublicVendorCloudHealthJob _healthCheckjob;
   
    public HealthCheckHub()
    {
        this._healthCheckjob = PublicVendorCloudHealthJob.Instance;
    }

    public IEnumerable<HealthCheckItemResponse> GetAllHealthCheckResponses()
    {
        return this._healthCheckjob.GetAllHealthCheckResponses();
    }
}
```

This is my Job class implementation:

```
public class PublicVendorCloudHealthJob : SkyJobGrain, IPublicVendorCloudHealthJob
{
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<HealthCheckItemResponse> _response;
    private static IConfiguration _configuration;
    private static IDeploymentElevator _deploymentElevator;
    private static IItineraryElevator _itineraryElevator;
    private static IResourceElevator _resourceElevator;

    public PublicVendorCloudHealthJob(IConfiguration configuration, IDeploymentElevator deploymentElevator, IItineraryElevator itineraryElevator, IResourceElevator resourceElevator)
        : base(configuration, deploymentElevator, itineraryElevator, resourceElevator)
    {
        this.Clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HealthCheckHub>().Clients;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _deploymentElevator = deploymentElevator;
        _itineraryElevator = itineraryElevator;
        _resourceElevator = resourceElevator;
        this._response = new ConcurrentBag<HealthCheckItemResponse>
        {
            new HealthCheckItemResponse
            {
                Description = "Larissa test"
            }
        };
    }

    public override Task Execute(object obj)
    {
        this.Clients.All.publishHealthChecks("Larissa" + DateTime.UtcNow);
        return TaskDone.Done;
    }

    public static PublicVendorCloudHealthJob Instance => (PublicVendorCloudHealthJob)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PublicVendorCloudHealthJob), _configuration, _deploymentElevator, _itineraryElevator, _resourceElevator);

    public IEnumerable<HealthCheckItemResponse> GetAllHealthCheckResponses()
    {
        return this._response;
    }
    private IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> Clients { get; }
}
```

I also configure the hub in Owin startup.cs file like this:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = null;
GlobalHost.Configuration.TransportConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
app.MapSignalR();
```

For the JS client side, after I get the generated proxy, I did something like this:

```
signalrService.signalr().then((value) => {
    if (value === "success"){
        const healthCheckHub = $.connection.healthCheckHub;
        const healthCheckHub2 = $.connection.hub.proxies.healthcheckhub;
        healthCheckHub.client.publishHealthChecks = (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        };
        healthCheckHub2.client.publishHealthChecks = (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        };
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start().done(() => {
            const defaultData = healthCheckHub.server.getAllHealthCheckResponses();
            console.log(defaultData);
        });
    }
});
```

I'm using

- Chrome v.51
- SingalR.core v.2.2.0
- Owin